# Appropriate journals for case study article about teaching math to learning-disabled student

Tags: education-research, publishing, disability, journals

Many scholarly articles have been written about the relationship between low working memory and math learning difficulties.  There's not much written about what to do about it.

I would like to write a scholarly article that is a case study of a child who tested with single-digit working memory (due to epilepsy), and who was four years behind grade level in math.  The article would describe specific activities and approaches that worked well for him, that other teachers and tutors can use to guide their work in similarly challenging situations.  What are some possible journals for a case study?

Related information: [Tutoring elementary student who reverses left and right](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/tutoring-elementary-student-who-reverses-left-and-right)

Comment: Probably this will depend on the background of the author(s). A cursory search in google scholar suggests the [**Australian Journal of Learning Difficulties**](http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/rald20/current) as a reasonable (looking...) choice. Another option, depending on how the article is constructed, could be the [**Journal of Cognition and Development**](http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/hjcd20/current).